# Describe the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by the vectors

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Please help me with this question.

Describe the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by the vectors in
$S=\{(−1,1,4),(1,−1,4),(1,1,4)\}$.

Comment: Drawing a diagram might help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand which subspace they span, we could start by seeing if the vectors in $S$ are linearly indipendent. Recall that the set $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly indipendent if the only solution of:
$$
c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=0
$$
is $c_1,c_2,c_3=0$.
An easy way to check linear indipendence is to see if the determinant of the matrix obtained by these vectors is different from $0$.
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1\\
4 & 4 & 4
\end{vmatrix}
$$

If we compute it, we get that the determinant is $16$. Therefore the vectors are linearly indipendent and the space spanned is $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

See if they are linearly independent. If they are, then they span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$.